# DAILY & Bonus Series NPC's and locations

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been banging around search results for NPC locations of Bonus Quest starters.  I can't seem to find anything like this:  Hoth Bonus Series NPC Starter:  Orbital Station (x,y), Prerequisites: (x, y, z). Etc.

Does anyone know of a site where this kind of info is given?  I'm specifically trying to find the Hoth NPC to kick off the DAILY series, like that given on Belsavis. ie, On Belsavis, I know that I can start the Daily series by going to the NPC's at "Wilderness" Outpost.  Where is this same location/NPC group on Hoth?  Alderaan? Tatooine?

Oh and yes I've done all the quests that I can find except Heroics, and am level 50 (Republic, Smuggler).  I'm assuming that having finished the Bonus series on Hoth gives me access to the dailies by level 50.

Any help is much appreciated! Cheers~

Comment: the swtor-spy.com website has information such as prerequisites. it doesn't, however, seem to give exact coordinates - but may still be of use. Are you Republic or Imperial?

Comment: @jfpONe23 - I added in the information that you added in the second question you posted.  In the future, if you need to add information to a question, there is an edit button right at the bottom of the question - feel free to add anything that will clarify what you are asking.  Welcome to Gaming SE!

Comment: There are level 50 dailies on Hoth? This is news to me.

Answer (score 1):

On doing further research, I'm pretty sure you're mistaken. There *are no level 50 daily quests on Hoth* to the best of my knowledge.

You'll find max-level daily quests at the Fleet, on Belsavis, and on Ilum.

Answer (score 0):

According to SWTOR-SPY.COM, the Hoth Bonus series can be started by accepting quests from either:

- For Republic Characters, the quest giver is General Ilic Nadab at
  Aurek Base.
- For Imperial Characters, the quest giver is Captain Graich at Dorn
  Base. He stands by the Shuttle at the top of this map.

Comment: Ok thanks for those answers, but really I'm looking for the giver of the DAILY quests which are higher level, and ONLY available after doing the bonus series.  Sorry if my title was misleading.  I've since edited the title.